# The deal between "Mary and me" vs. "Mary and I"

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, word-order, politeness

I think "Mary and me," even though it sounds odd to the ear, is correct, but my choice is between:  "I've forgotten everything about the deal between Mary and me" and "I've forgotten everything about the deal between Mary and I."  I'm wondering if the words "deal between" have any grammatical significance on whether I should be using "I" or "me" here.  Any thoughts?